# XCODE iOS mask image while preserving a zone

Tags: ios, image-processing, mask

How can I mask an image with 3 different areas:

1. transparent background
2. a black area where will be place my image
3. a white area I want to keep white

Do you know if it is possible? and how?

I know how to do without the white area.

Answer (score 0):

2 views, with some masks...

A view with a white background containing an image view with your image.
The image view's layer has a mask. The white view's layer has a mask.

Would this work for you?

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageview alloc] initWithImage:image];
[view addSubview:imageView];
imageView.layer.mask = maskToShowWhite;
view.layer.mask = maskToShowTransparent;
```

Or you could just mask the image and draw the white over the top in a drawRect?